# Why properties added via Object.defineProperty are not iterable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, v8

Consider this code:

```
var a = {
    get aa() {
        return 'aa';
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(
    a,
    'bb',
    {
        get: function() {
            return 'bb';
        }
    }
);

for(p in a) {
    sys.puts(p + ': ' + a[p]);
}
```

The output is:

```
aa: aa
```

However property bb is perfectly accessible and working.

Why 'bb' is not visible in for..in loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `enumerable` to `true`.

(*You could also give **[`getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)** a try,but I'm not sure how cross browser that is.*)

```
var a = {
    get aa() {
        return 'aa';
    }
}, arr = [];

Object.defineProperty(
    a,
    'bb',
    {
        get: function() {
            return 'bb';
        },
        enumerable: true
    }
);

for(p in a) {
    arr.push(p + ': ' + a[p]);
}
alert(arr.join("\n"));
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXqST/)

Answer (score 1):

Because this behaviour may be practical for adding in meta properties. The behaviour can be changed by setting the enumerable property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 0):

The boolean fields of an object property's "meta-properties" all default to `false`, including the `enumerable` property.